# Using the form tag even though what's being submitted is through ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I had a general question about best practices.

Now usually when a form is being coded you add the `<form></form>` tags around it, but is that necessary if the form that's being submitted is being submitted via javascript? Especially if you don't have a submit button and just a `<button>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but is that necessary

No, but it **is** best practise.

> Especially if you don't have a submit button and just a `<button>`?

The default type of a button element *is* submit, and if it is supposed to submit the data to the server, then best practise is not to change that.

---

Use [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement), write [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Make an HTML form that "just works".

Then write JavaScript to Ajaxify it.

Bind your event handlers with JavaScript.

Use `preventDefault()` if the JavaScript runs successfully.

Then you maximise the chances that, if there is a problem (such as an error in your script, dependancy on a DOM feature not supported by the user's browser, the JS not loading because of a network glitch or being caught up by overzealous adblocking plugins, etc, etc) the worst case will be that the browser will submit the data using the form and load a new page instead of sitting there silently failing and leaving the user wondering what has happened.

Comment: This was an amazing answer, thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

Form tags are not necessary when submitting with js, or at least when via ajax.